# Google universal analytics goal tracking hit type

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal

I am using Google UA to track goals. 
It means every time someone calls a number on the page goal number increments.
This is passed through HTTP request.
My question is:
As google requires these 4 parameters to be in the payload data:

```
v=1             // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID.
&t=             // Hit Type.
What should I set for Hit Type "t=" ??
```

Comment: Goals are calculated internally by Google analytics. its not something you send.

Comment: how can Google analytics count phone calls internally? 
I have to set a http request to count phonecall as a goal...

Comment: That's a hit not a goal, or maybe an event.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hit type**
>
> Required for all hit types.
>
> The type of hit. Must be one of 'pageview', 'screenview', 'event',
>   'transaction', 'item', 'social', 'exception', 'timing'.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#hit

Simply use a pageview/screenview, as this is the basic metric in GA (you need to add a document location dl, too, and then you can set up a location based goal).

Comment: is this not going to double my page views?
I am tracking page views and phone calls so if someones enters the page it counts as one page view and if someone calls a number on that page it counts as page view for goal

Comment: It will track a distinct pageview every time you send a tracking call. You can tell them apart by using a distinct document location.